# Angular 1.6: ng-blur and ng-focus does not work on elements in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I am working using Angular 1.6 on an application. Using `ng-click` and `ng-focus` has worked fine in the past on different elements. However, I found I am having trouble getting it to work within `ng-repeat`.

**For example:** Using ng-repeat creates 4 elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="" ng-init="isFocus=true">
        <div ng-show="isFocus">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]"><a href="" ng-blur="isFocus=false" >test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work. When I tab onto or click a list element and leave on an element `ng-blur` should change to false. it seems to do it but in some sort of different scope. If I print out the values you can see it turns false on leave. However it will not set it to the variable for the page so that `ng-show` on the div is now false and hides. You can see and try it out at the jsFiddle created.

**https://jsfiddle.net/Lightk3ira/4xc1ev6b/**

I also created a fiddle with no `ng-repeat`, notice tabbing or clicking on the list item and then clicking off that `ng-blur` kicks off and sets the variable globally to false like it should and the ng-show hides the div because it is false.

**https://jsfiddle.net/Lightk3ira/03tus8yg/**

I would like ng-blur and ng-focus to work on items inside `ng-repeat`, however, it does not seem to work correctly as you can see from the fiddle. It seems the variable does change to false as it outputs it beside the item. However notice the paragraph tag at the top says the variable is still set to 'true' which is why the div stays showing because `isFocus` is equal to true still.

I cannot seem to find out why this happens or how to counter it so that Angular works as expected like in the second fiddle with no `ng-repeat`.

Comment: this code is breaking one of the cardinal rules of angular.  "**Always** use a dot (`.`) in angular bindings!".

Comment: by using an object property instead of a primitive, you can avoid this conflict.  https://jsfiddle.net/zp63srmz/

Comment: in your "broken" code, you are creating a *new* `isFocus` primitive in each iteration of `ng-repeat`, causing the link to only affect itself.  In the "fixed" version, using an object, a new object is not created, rather the property of the existing object is updated.  The "broken" code isn't really broken;  having a primitive created for each iteration of `ng-repeat` can be very useful in certain circumstances, like having an `active` value for individual links, for example.

Comment: So 'ctrl' that would be my actual controller correct? That was a great answer. I am still new to Angular and that explained alot. I really appreciate it. Can you please write it as an answer so I can give you credit? Thanks again!